# Convert data_numeric to Date in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, lubridate

I have a dataset that have a numeric date column. How can I convert 2017.31 in a numeric form to the date of "2017-4-22"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That may be Apr 23, not the 22nd, but perhaps this is the right start:

```r
vec <- 2017.31
as.POSIXct(paste(trunc(vec), trunc((vec %% 1) * 365)), format = "%Y %j", tz = "UTC")
# [1] "2017-04-23 UTC"
```

The `%j` code is described in [`?strptime`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html).